# PL/SQL Cursor and Array of different size

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql, cursor

I want to store the content of a **cursor** in an associative **array** (Table index by binary_integer). But in the same array I also want to store an **additional variable**, say a boolean.

My cursor has n elements per row and the array is defined to have n+1 elements (n with the same %type as the cursorelements), the last one being the boolean.

What I whant is something like this

```
for cursorrow in cursor(...) 
loop
  array(row i) := cursorrow, boolean_variable;
end loop;
```

|1|2|...|n|n+1| := |1|2|...|n|, |1|

Unfortunately I can't get it to work.
Anybody knows how to do it?

Comment: Create a record..and then create a type of that records and store it,.

Comment: If I got it right then this could be done in two ways:

1. The records has two fields, one is a rowtype, the other the additional variable. In this case I loose the access on the individual collumnfields (like cursor.field1 --> array.field1) what is fatal for the further program.

2. I have to (declare and) assign every field value on its own. This is what should work but I hoped it could be done more elegant.

Thanks a lot, however, for the swift reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about defining a composite record type consisting of a `%rowtype` record and a Boolean?

Test setup:

```
create table demo_table
( some_id integer primary key
, some_name varchar2(30) not null unique
, some_type varchar2(10) not null );

insert all
    into demo_table values (1, 'One', 'X' )
    into demo_table values (2, 'Two', 'Y' )
    into demo_table values (3, 'Three', 'Z' )
select * from dual;
```

Test:
(Edit: added `dbms_output` messages within loop)

```
declare
    subtype demo_rectype is demo_table%rowtype;

    type demo_rec is record
    ( details demo_rectype
    , somecheck boolean );

    type demo_tt is table of demo_rec index by pls_integer;
    t_demo demo_tt;

    cursor c_demo is select * from demo_table;
begin
    for r in c_demo
    loop
        t_demo(c_demo%rowcount).details := r;
        t_demo(c_demo%rowcount).somecheck := dbms_random.value < 0.5;

        dbms_output.put_line
        ( t_demo(c_demo%rowcount).details.some_name || ': ' ||
          case t_demo(c_demo%rowcount).somecheck
              when true then 'TRUE'
              when false then 'FALSE'
              else 'NULL'
          end );
    end loop;

    dbms_output.new_line();
    dbms_output.put_line('Array t_demo contains ' || t_demo.count || ' items.');
end;
```

Output:

```
One: FALSE
Two: FALSE
Three: TRUE

Array t_demo contains 3 items.
```

Comment: @william..Nice code,,asking out of curiosity,how to print the values of cursor (each record) here.

Comment: I think that is the problem. The values are stored, sure. But now, the fields in "details" can not be addressed individually anymore. 
(Provided I did not get that wrong)

Comment: I've updated my answer with some examples. Basically you can read it back the same way you put it in, i.e. `array(index).record.field`. If outside the cursor loop, you'd replace `c_demo%rowcount` with a variable (usually named `i` by convention).

Comment: So actually the addressing works by adding a new level into the qualified name.
That is pretty easy and actually obvious but I did not get it. Thank you @WilliamRobertson!

To put it in other Words:
Say I have a Record rec with Fileds a,b and c. I can address a and b by writing rec.a and rec.b. If c would contain a %rowtype-structure with columns x and y, I could address them with rec.c.x and rec.c.y.
Again, now I see it, it is very obvious.
 Thanks again everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since the record type differs by 1 field from the table structure (i.e. the boolean), you can not assign the cursor row to the record type in 1 assignment statement. You need to do it for every table column individually:

```
for cursorrow in cursor(...) 
loop
  array(row i).col1 := cursorrow.col1;
  array(row i).col2 := cursorrow.col2;
  ...
  array(row i).coln := cursorrow.coln;
  array(row i).boolean_variable := some_boolean_value;
end loop;
```

Comment: Thank you. That is what I hoped would not be the answer but good to know there is no other way!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments,you can create a record and do it. You can use the below procedure to achieve your requirement.

```
create or replace procedure proc_test
as

  cursor cur_tab is 
   select a  --have selected only 1 column..you can choose many
    from test;

  TYPE  var_temp  IS TABLE OF cur_tab%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  v_var              var_temp; 

 /**You can add columns selected in you cursor here in your record****/
 TYPE abc IS RECORD
  (
   id          varchar2(100), 
   orig_name   boolean      
   );

  TYPE  xx IS TABLE OF abc ;

  -- initialization of record
  v_xx    xx := xx() ;  

  t   boolean:=TRUE;    

 begin


  open cur_tab;

   fetch cur_tab bulk collect into v_var;

  close cur_tab;

  for i in 1..v_var.count
   loop

     v_xx.extend;

     v_xx(i).id := v_var(i).a;
     v_xx(i).orig_name := t;

      dbms_output.put_line (v_xx(i).id ||'----'||sys.diutil.bool_to_int(v_xx(i).orig_name));

     ---OR

      dbms_output.put_line (v_xx(i).id ||'----'||case when v_xx(i).orig_name = true then 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' end );

   end loop;

  exception
  when others then 
  null;

 end;
```

Call:

```
execute proc_test;
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.
If I get you right, I would still have to call every field/column of the cursor separately. In this case, there should be no improvement to just assign every field/column the way like Martin Schapendonk illustrated above.
Right?

Comment: Yes..if you need it. Or you can further complicate it by making a subtype of a table and then using the subtype to a record column. William explained this.

Comment: @Rekisyhp..Not sure if the way Martin showed the assignment will work.!! Did your try that.

Comment: Yes, this is what I have as current solution. But since I have several columns already but only want to add one, I was hoping to find something more elegant.

Comment: I just could not understand how he was assigning the last boolean variable to array, If that is the looking best solution to you then, go ahead.

Comment: It is not looking best but it works (or I did something very wrong):
The thing is, that the array is defined collumn by collumn and provides all fields of the cursor plus an additional boolean. Unfortumately, one has to assign the values for every column (and the boolean) separately.

Comment: Yes but its one time activity and i guess once you had created a procedure like i said, you wont have to do it again and again..

Comment: You are right, but it might be a recurring one time activity.
But anyway, i think the question is answered.
Thank you for your effort!